# is it possible to set timout in Axios get request?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, get, axios, timeout

In a small VueJS app, I'm using `Axios` to handle `HTTP` requests!
I have a simple `GET request` and I want to add a `timeout` parameter to my request, but it's not working...

are we allowed to use a timeout in GET request or am I doing something wrong?

this is my code:
...
Vue.prototype.$http = Axios
...

```
this.$http.get(stringUrl, {parameters: {limit: 5000}},timeout: 30000).then(data => {...})
```

GET works fine but, but it's instant. I want the GET request to wait for 30000 then get data, but it's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Axios timeout is responsible for *response timeout*. If you want to wait for the data for about 30 seconds, you can use a `Promise` to wait for about 30 seconds.

```
async function getData() {
   const data = await this.$http.get(stringUrl, {parameters: {limit: 5000}},timeout: 30000)
   return new Promise(res =>  setTimeout(res(data), 30000))
}
```

Comment: From how I read it, OP wants to wait 30 seconds before doing the GET-request, not do the GET-request immediately and then wait 30 seconds before returning the response. Also, in this case you are not doing anything with `data`; Shouldn't you be returning that in the resolve function?